# Expand column in pandas DataFrame into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pandas-groupby

I know this can be done with `pivot`, I just don't know how. When I tried, I got too many rows with many `nan` values. I have a number of objects identified by their `x` and `y` coordinates. I want to get one row for each such object, as in this example:

```
input = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'dim_name':['height',  'height', 'width', 'width'], 'dim_val': [1, 2, 10, 20], 'x': [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2], 
                            'y':[0.6, 0.7, 0.6, 0.7]})

output = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'x':[0.1, 0.2], 'y': [0.6, 0.7], 'height': [1, 2],  'width':[10, 20]})
```

How do I do this in pandas?

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Seems quite straightforward… `df.pivot(index=['x', 'y'], columns='dim_name', values='dim_val').reset_index()`

Comment: Something of that sort, but I suppose I had the args all at the wrong places, like
`x.pivot(index='dim_name', columns=['x', 'y'], values='dim_val').reset_index()`

Comment: that's why you should always provide your code (and carefully read the docs) ;)